# TF Merge command in Powershell script task is not working

Tags: powershell, merge, azure-devops, tfvc

I am having powershell task with the following commands in my pipeline which is running using custom agent pool.

```
$TFFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"

$mergeCommand = " merge $/MyProject/dev $/MyProject/test /recursive"

Start-Process "$TFFile" "$mergeCommand"

$comment = "Automated merge check-in"

$CheckinToTarget = " checkin $/MyProject/test /comment:$comment /recursive /noprompt"

Start-Process "$TFFile" "$CheckinToTarget"
```

The pipeline is successfully running. But the changes in source branch is not merged with target branch. Please let me know what is missing in this scripts.

Comment: There is no output?

Comment: Is there any information in the powershell task's log?

Comment: @Shayki - Yes. Pipeline executed successfully. But it is not merged

Comment: @Levi Lu - I don't see any useful information in log to debug

Comment: After some fix in the scripts, I found the reason for not working. Actually it throwing the error as "Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'. When I search for this error, some links suggest to use "tf workfold" command. But that command throwing the error as "TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/XXXXX". Anyone please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this solution to help others who are facing the issue like me. Using /loginType:OAuth with the command solves my issues.