# How to auto merge all code to another branch in azure devops with TFVC?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

Our previous on-prem TFS ran XAML builds. Once a changeset had been processed the XAML ran some power shell to map both branches to temp folders, and get the code that was different between them and auto-merge from trunk to branch.

I’m trying to use Classic Pipelines in Azure Devops Services (cloud)  to achieve the same result.
The power shell script runs but I think it’s not authenticated, or the workspace isn’t deterministic. There’s no visible errors in the power shell output in dev.azure.com. 
The power shell script ran tf.exe commmands.

I thought there might be an azure devops task that could do this common operation (merge a change set). I’ve seen some solutions for git, but nothing for TFVC (Cloud based).

Here's the powershell so you can see what we do:

```
# Get the tfs command line tool
$tf = get-item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.EXE"
$rootBranchLocation = "C:\temp\M16"
$branchBranchLocation = "C:\temp\M16Branch"
$rootBranch="$/MooD/M16" 
$branchBranch="$/MooD/M16Branch" 

if(!(Test-Path -Path $rootBranchLocation )){
    New-Item -Path $rootBranchLocation -ItemType Directory
}
if(!(Test-Path -Path $branchBranchLocation )){
New-Item -Path $branchBranchLocation -ItemType Directory
}

# Temporarily map the two branches so we can do the merge etc. Do not need to do a get. Shouldn't be slow.
& $tf workfold /map $rootBranch $rootBranchLocation
& $tf workfold /map $branchBranch $branchBranchLocation

# List the changes that haven't been merged yet
Write-Host (& $tf merge /candidate $rootBranchLocation $branchBranchLocation /recursive)
# Try do the merge
& $tf merge $rootBranchLocation $branchBranchLocation /recursive /noprompt
# Get the exit code for the merge
$exitMerge=$LastExitCode
# If the exit code was 0 then there were no conflicts (or no changes) so do a check in into the branch
if ($exitMerge -eq 0) { 
    & $tf checkin /comment:"Automerge from M16" /recursive /noprompt /notes:"Code Reviewer"="None - Automerge";   
    # Get the exit code for the checkin
    $exitCheckin=$LastExitCode
    # If you checkin with no changes the you get an errorlevel 1
    if ($exitCheckin -eq 1) { $exitCheckin=0 } 
}

# Unmap the two branches we set up 
& $tf workfold /unmap $rootBranchLocation
& $tf workfold /unmap $branchBranchLocation

if ($exitMerge -ne 0) {
    Write-Error ("Merge to M16Branch did not complete. The most likely cause is conflict. Try manual merge")
    exit 1
}

exit 0
```

But it would be awesome if we didn't need the powershell script at all.

Comment: Hi, does you store the code in a Azure Devops Service repo(TFVC) or a TFS repo? And what does the task script you use look like?

Comment: We store the code in TFVC, in the cloud. I'll update the post with the powershell.

Comment: Set the variable `System.Debug=true` and run the pipeline again to check the detailed log, it would help us locate the cause of the issue. Also, it seems you're not authorized, try `tf workspaces` command with `/loginType:OAuth /login:.,[OAuth token]` option. Maybe this [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60448133/tf-merge-command-in-powershell-script-task-is-not-working) can help.

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue?